# vue dataset outputting undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass the value and index of an object to a vue method. 
My methods is able to show the value but the index is undefined.
Please advise where I did wrong.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<div class="select is-info">
    <select @change="change_default_canvas($event.target.value, 
       $event.target.dataset.index)" id="select_business_model_version">
       <option>Select Version</option>
       <option v-for="(history,index) in all_business_models_hisotry" :key="index" :value="history.canvas_id" :data-index="index">Date : {{history.date_submitted}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

`$event.target.dataset.index` is outputting `undefined`

Comment: You need to have a data attribute in you HTML i guess

Comment: `v-model` can work on the select tag. Reference [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/7q5jtycf/)

Comment: @Haque I am using the data attribite. see `:data-index="index"`

Comment: @ApplePie ,Uhh missed that :( does `$event.currentTarget.dataset.index` work??

Comment: `$event.target` is the `<select>`, not the `<option>`

Comment: @Haque Sorry, it is not working

Comment: @StephenThomas how to make it work for `<option>`

Comment: You can’t. Use the value to find the appropriate option

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the selected **option** element and get the data-index from there. Something like this:

```
$event.target.options[$event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.index
```

Answer (score 0):

User **selectedIndex** (*index - 1* actually to skip the first option) instead:

```
<div id="myComp">
  <div class="select is-info">
      <select @change="change_default_canvas($event.target.value, 
         $event.target.selectedIndex)" id="select_business_model_version">
         <option>Select Version</option>
         <option v-for="(history,index) in all_business_models_hisotry" :key="index" :value="history.canvas_id" :data-index="index">Date : {{history.date_submitted}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ysa14cf/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `@change` to the following:

```
<select @change="change_default_canvas" id="select_business_model_version">
```

In your `change_default_canvas` method will look like the following:

```
change_default_canvas(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    console.log(event.target.dataset.index)
    /* your logic here */
}
```